how do i hide a custom tab bar in subviews
I am learning about swiftUI navigation stack and Tab Bars, most tutorials just show implementation of the tab bars. i am trying to hide my custom tab bar in subviews. Please can someone explain what to do so that I can learn and take note of it for future references. Thanks in advance
struct MainTabbedView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    @Environment(\.isTabBarVisible) var isTabBarVisible
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                HomeView()
                    .tag(0)

                FavoriteView()
                    .tag(1)

                FantasyView_Preview()
                    .tag(2)

                ProfileView()
                    .tag(3)
            }

            if isTabBarVisible {
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach((TabbedItems.allCases), id: \.self) { item in
                            Button {
                                selectedTab = item.rawValue
                            } label: {
                                CustomTabItem(imageName: item.iconName, title: item.title, isActive: (selectedTab == item.rawValue))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(6)
                }
                .frame(height: 70)
                .background(Color.yinmnBlue.opacity(0.2))
                .cornerRadius(35)
                .padding(.horizontal, 26)
            }
        }
extension MainTabbedView {
    func CustomTabItem(imageName: String, title: String, isActive: Bool) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName:imageName)
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .foregroundColor(isActive ? .black : .gray)
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            if isActive {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(isActive ? .black : .gray)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: isActive ? .infinity : 60, height: 60)
        .background(isActive ? Color.yinmnBlue.opacity(0.4) : .clear)
        .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}


HomeView.swift
struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var showsubview = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            Button(action: {
                showsubview = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Go to sub view")
            })
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showsubview) {
                navigation1(isPresented: $showsubview)
                    .environment(\.isTabBarVisible, false)
            }
        }
    }
}



i tried to use environment variables but it did not work
struct TabBarVisibilityKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = true
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isTabBarVisible: Bool {
        get { self[TabBarVisibilityKey.self] }
        set { self[TabBarVisibilityKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}


Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.
Some (minimal) code we can compile and run.
What is navigation1(isPresented: $showsubview)? Where is MainTabbedView called?

Environment values are for passing information down the view hierarchy, but in this case you want subviews to inform their parents of whether they want the tab bar to be shown. You should use a preference instead.
First, write a preference key
struct CustomTabBarVisiblePreference: PreferenceKey {
    // nil means "not set"
    static let defaultValue: Bool? = nil
    
    static func reduce(value: inout Bool?, nextValue: () -> Bool?) {
        guard let next = nextValue() else { return }
        value = next
    }
}

In the navigation destination of HomeView, set the preference to false:
struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var showsubview = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            Button(action: {
                showsubview = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Go to sub view")
            })
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showsubview) {
                Text("Destination")
                    // here:
                    .preference(key: CustomTabBarVisiblePreference.self, value: false)
            }
        }
    }
}

In the tab view, use a overlayPreferenceValue instead of a ZStack to overlay the tab bar. This way, you can read the preference value and determine whether to show a tab bar.
struct MainTabbedView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            HomeView()
                .tag(0)
            
            // I have replaced other views with simple Texts so that this is a minimal reproducible example
            Text("Favourites View")
                .tag(1)
            
            Text("Fantasy View")
                .tag(2)
            
            Text("Profile View")
                .tag(3)
        }
        .overlayPreferenceValue(CustomTabBarVisiblePreference.self, alignment: .bottom) { visible in
            // "!= false" here so that the tab bar is visible if the preference is not set
            if visible != false {
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<4, id: \.self) { item in
                            Button {
                                selectedTab = item
                            } label: {
                                CustomTabItem(imageName: "circle", title: "Title \(item)", isActive: selectedTab == item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(6)
                }
                .frame(height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                .cornerRadius(35)
                .padding(.horizontal, 26)
            }
        }
    }
}

// I refactored CustomTabItem as its own View struct
struct CustomTabItem: View {
    let imageName: String
    let title: String
    let isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName:imageName)
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .foregroundColor(isActive ? .black : .gray)
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            if isActive {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(isActive ? .black : .gray)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: isActive ? nil : 60, height: 60)
        .frame(maxWidth: isActive ? .infinity : nil)
        .background(isActive ? Color.blue.opacity(0.4) : .clear)
        .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}


thanks @Sweeper. this was informative

i would like to know in the case where there are multiple buttons that opens different subviews do i set the preference under each navigation destination? or i can just place it under the navigation stack?

@gillbates you should modify each destination, not the whole navigation stack. The navigation stack is always “visible”, so its preference will always “prevail” over its destinations.

i know this is a big ask, but do you do code reviews?
